# Employee with their manager levels

Tags: oracle

Please find below table structure .i need output in below mentioned format.

```
E_id    Name    Mg_id
1       Neel    2
2       Abhi    3
3       Neha    null

Output 

Name    Mgr_name1   Mgr_name2
Neel    Abhi        Neha
```

Comment: That's a simple self join

Comment: **Hint** : Conditional aggregation containing case..when expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the employee's name, their manager's name and their manager's manager's name then you can use:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT name AS name,
       PRIOR name AS mgr_name1,
       name AS mgr_name2
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  LEVEL = 3
START WITH e_id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR mg_id = e_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (E_id, Name, Mg_id) AS
SELECT 1, 'Neel', 2    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Abhi', 3    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Neha', NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME | MGR_NAME1 | MGR_NAME2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Neel | Abhi | Neha |

---

If you wanted to get the output when an employee has no manager and/or no manager's manager then you can use:

```sql
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT name AS name,
       CASE LEVEL
       WHEN 2
       THEN name
       WHEN 3
       THEN PRIOR name
       END AS mgr_name1,
       CASE LEVEL
       WHEN 3
       THEN name
       END AS mgr_name2
FROM   table_name 
WHERE  LEVEL = 3
OR     (LEVEL < 3 AND CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1)
START WITH e_id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR mg_id = e_id
```

or you could also use multiple self-joins:

```sql
SELECT t1.name,
       t2.name AS mgr_name1,
       t3.name AS mgr_name2
FROM   table_name t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t2
       ON t1.mg_id = t2.e_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table_name t3
       ON t2.mg_id = t3.e_id
WHERE  t1.e_id = 1;
```

*Note: using self-joins will require reading from the table once for each time the table is joined; this may be less efficient than using a hierarchical query (even though the query is simpler to write).*

Which both output the same, but if you run either of those two queries without the `START BY` filter or `WHERE` filter respectively then the output is:

| NAME | MGR_NAME1 | MGR_NAME2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Neel | Abhi | Neha |
| Abhi | Neha | *null* |
| Neha | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pwGA7kyx)